# PHP MySQL query to display list of event links in 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, joomla1.5

**Joomla 1.5.25**

**Fabrik 2.1**

**PHP 5.3.8**

- Fabrik Table: `jos_bully_table`
- Column: `bully_concat_name`
- Column: `datetime`

I count the # of times the `bully_concat_name` appears in the table with this PHP code, which updates the `b_name_count` column:

```
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$sql = <<<EOL
UPDATE jos_bully_table AS jbt1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT jbt2.bully_concat_name, COUNT(*) AS b_name_count
FROM jos_bully_table AS jbt2
GROUP BY jbt2.bully_concat_name
) AS jbt3
ON jbt3.bully_concat_name = jbt1.bully_concat_name
SET jbt1.b_name_count = jbt3.b_name_count
EOL;

mysql_query($sql);

echo "<!-- SQL Error ".mysql_error()." -->";
```

I then display the # by pulling the value of b_name_count with this code:

```
$rowid = JRequest::getVar('rowid');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT b_name_count FROM `jos_bully_table` WHERE id = '$rowid'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

echo '<div id="inc_count">';
echo '<p style="text-align: center;">';
echo $row['b_name_count'];
echo '</p>';
echo '</div>';
```

I'd like to display the list of related dates when the name appeared in the database in 2 columns under the `b_name_count` #. The datetime column contains records like this: 2011-11-16 17:13:01

I'd like to display this date as 11/16/2011 (`%m/%d/%Y`).

Answer (score 0):

First off, you really really need to look into using [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s:

```
$sql = <<<EOL
UPDATE jos_bully_table AS jbt1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT jbt2.bully_concat_name, COUNT(*) AS b_name_count
   FROM jos_bully_table AS jbt2
   GROUP BY jbt2.bully_concat_name
) AS jbt3
ON jbt3.bully_concat_name = jbt1.bully_concat_name
SET jbt1.b_name_count = jbt3.b_name_count
EOL;
```

Note the lack of `\n` and all the `. "` type operators, making for a MUCH more readable query.

As for you date issue, you don't mention the name of the column (I think), but you can use MySQL's [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to do your formatting for you:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`datetimefield`, '%m/%d/%Y') ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code, but still need help with the initial request. I want to display the corresponding dates (datetime column) when the name appeared in the table.